# Does HTML5 Canvas pixel size depend on the canvas size?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm drawing simple lines with the HTML5 canvas:

```
context = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
context.moveTo(150, 20);
context.lineTo(300, 20);
context.stroke();
```

When my canvas CSS changes from:

```
canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

to

```
canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

the stroke width and height also double! What gives?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CSS only determines its *visible* size. Change the `width` and `height` attributes in the HTML to adjust the actual number of pixels that make it up. If in the HTML it is 100x100, and in the CSS 200x200, it will be visually scaled by 2X.